# in Drupal 7, if you follow a group, how to notify you when the group update their content?

Tags: drupal, notifications

I want to build such functionality that allows the user to follow the other users, and when the followed person is updating the information, the follower can get notified for what they are doing.

I think to build the follow functionality, I can use the flag module, but for the notification, what kind of modules are good to work with? I am confused; there are too many modules like notification, messaging, even nodejs module can notify, is there any tutorial that can give me some idea about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear from your description if you need to follow users or groups.

If you are just following other users all you really need is Flag and [Notifications](http://dgo.to/notifications).

If you want to notify users when any new content is added to a group, you'll need [OG Notifications](http://dgo.to/og_notifications) which does exactly that. From the project page:

> User will be able to subscribe/unsubscribe on the all new nodes posted in a group. And will be able to edit his subscriptions.